# Safe to have an NextJS api endpoint that returns the access token

Tags: authentication, next.js, auth0

I am building an admin portal with NextJS and nextjs-auth0. I need to allow the front end to call an external GraphQL server. Would it be a safe approach to have an NextJS api endpoint that returns the access token and store it in memory? The front end would then track the expiration time and request a new access token before expiration.

I don't want to use a proxy if I don't have to. A proxy adds more complexity and requires more resources as well as increase latency.